# Иерархическое древо ответов PHP

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Столкнулся с проблемой (искал в сети, не нашёл ничего толкового), как реализовать иерархическое древо вопросов ответов. (Пример на картинке)

Вопрос — То что отправляет пользователь.
Ответ — То что получает пользователь в ответ

Вопросы приходят в формате JSON от ВКонтакте.

В сети описывают древо разделов для сайтов и вывод из MySQL, но это не то что нужно. Буду благодарен за помощь...

Comment: какое иерархическое дерево? Хоть убей не вижу никакой иерархии.
Ты делаешь что то типа бота которому присылают сообщения, а он на них отвечает?

Comment: @singlesly По сути да, но суть в том что бы он понимал команды в строгой последовательности. То есть если ему писать в последовательности А->Б->В->Г он отвечает и работает, но если ему писать в последовательности А->В->Г->Б он ничего не станет делать или отправит ранее заготовленный ответ...

Comment: @singlesly, обновил изображение для большего понимания...

Comment: Ну а что вам непонятно? В php можно делать вложенные массивы. Вы можете создавать любую сложную структуру. Если обернёте это всё в класс, то будет вообще красиво

Comment: Не претендую на истинность. Я просто так прикинул исходя из опыта. И от чего бы я отталкивался.
Тебе нужно будет для каждого пользователя, для каждого сообщение хранить информацию о состояний команды.
То есть пользователь 1 сейчас написал команду А. Значит у его доступны только команды Б и С.
А пользователь 2 написал команду Д значит бот может ответить только на  У и Ф. Если команда не доступна, то бот что то отвечает дефолтное сообщение.
Вообще сложная вещь и не удобно для пользователя им постоянно придется выходить из диапазона команд на уровень выше. Но вполне реализуемо.

Comment: У тебя по факту примитивные команды, почему просто не сделать список? Куда проще будет. Я понимаю если бы был какой то тест где следующий вопрос зависит от предыдущего. А так. Вообще смысла не вижу.

Comment: @singlesly в основном все это затеял только из-за скидывания изображений (Так как есть команды (например) "Скинь котика", "Скинь собачку", "Скинь дерево"). И что бы каждый раз не писать "Скинь …" думал как можно облегчить это.

Например он просит скинуть котиков, получает изображение, потом пишет "ещё" и он снова получает изображение котиков. 
Потом он просит скинут собаку, а после пишет "ещё" и получает соответствующее изображение

Comment: @singlesly по поводу выхода на уровень выше. В теории можно вроде сделать тайм-аут после которого он сам будет возвращать пользователя на соответствующий уровень. А вот как сделать и где хранить, это думаю для меня сейчас будет очень сложно... =(

Comment: да хранить можно в обычной БД какой нибудь может редис, sqlite, даже mysql подойдет не проблема. Можно разбить на команды по типу. И в БД просто хранить это состояние и потом если пользователь написал еще, проверить этот тип состояния и если по ему доступна команда, то дать ответ.